# How to get the value of each cell in a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I wanna ask a question about cell array. Suppose I have a cell array
    `C={[2 1], [3 5], [15 6]};`
I'd like to get all first value of each cell, which are [2, 3 , 15]
however, when I type
`C{:}(1);`
or
`C(:)(1);`
There would be some mistakes.
So what is the simplist way to get those numbers.

Comment: You may want to test `C{:}` in the terminal window. Note that every cell is evaluated separately.

Answer (score 4):

If every cell is a vector and **has** the same amount of elements, one way is to create a matrix by stacking all of these cells together and extract out the first column.  Use [`vertcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) to help you do that:

```
CMat = vertcat(C{:});
out = CMat(:,1);
```

If every cell **does not** have the same amount of elements, one way is to use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html).  Use an anonymous function to extract out the first element over each cell array:

```
out = cellfun(@(x) x(1), C);
```

The benefit of the above approach is that it doesn't matter if each cell is a vector or matrix.  It'll extract the first element for a vector or the top-left corner for a matrix.